# Zen theme doesn't append content titles to breadcrumbs

Tags: breadcrumbs, theming

I've inherited a site with a subtheme designed on Zen 7x-5.4 to maintain and I'm having a problem with the breadcrumbs. I've checked the append content title to breadcrumb options in Appearance=>Settings however this doesn't seem to have any effect on the breadcrumb trail (i.e. the individual content page titles aren't displayed in the breadcrumb). So, I assume something must be overriding the breadcrumb settings through the UI. I'm not sure what that could be, or where it would be set/configured. I've looked through the template.php, and theme-settings.php files. I have the following options set in the mytheme.info file

```
settings[zen_breadcrumb]           = yes
settings[zen_breadcrumb_separator] = ' › '
settings[zen_breadcrumb_home]      = 1
settings[zen_breadcrumb_trailing]  = 0
settings[zen_breadcrumb_title]     = 0
settings[zen_skip_link_anchor]     = main-menu
settings[zen_skip_link_text]       = Jump to navigation
settings[zen_html5_respond_meta][] = respond
settings[zen_html5_respond_meta][] = html5
settings[zen_html5_respond_meta][] = meta
settings[zen_rebuild_registry]     = 1
settings[zen_wireframes]           = 0
```

But changing the breadcrumb trailing or title values to 1, and flushing the theme registry didn't pull anything off.

For further context, I do have one breadcrumb set with the Path Breadcrumbs module. For development purposes I have css aggregation turned off.

So, what is preventing my theme from adding the content title to the breadcrumbs and or how to do find where the conflict is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme breadcrumbs were being overridden by the Path Breadcrumb module. You can fix this in the Path Breadcrumb settings.